# Using Selenium in Python to select a drop down menu item

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I've found many sources on selecting drop down menus, but I've tried every different way I can think of and I am still getting 'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:'
The drop down menu has a list of Model Years for cars.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
#Code
try:
    drop1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div["
except Exception as ex:
     print(f"full path\n", ex)                                             "2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select"))

try:
    drop1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='5fceb621-d70c-4471-92de-c2356e453314']/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"))
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"trunc path\n", ex)
    
try:
    drop1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, "sModelYear"))
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"By Name\n", ex)
```

Here's what the HTML of the website I'm using looks like

```
<select id="Model Year-5fceb621-d70c-4471-92de-c2356e453314" name="sModelYear">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022">2022</option>
                    <option value="">All</option></select>
```

And here's the output of my code:

```
full path
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select"}


trunc path
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='5fceb621-d70c-4471-92de-c2356e453314']/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"}


By Name
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="sModelYear"]"}
```

I copy and pasted the HTML path on the inspect element, for the first two "try"'s and then just used the name tag for the third, but I couldn't get any of them to recognize the drop down menu.

Comment: It's possible the dropdown is not yet populated when selenium searched for it. You can add a wait.

Comment: @tim I have a time.sleep(10) before this block of code. I can interact with the page during that sleep time too. I’m pretty sure it is populated.